# Invertir filas a columnas - SQL

Tags: sql, tsql

Estoy obteniendo una consulta SQL pero quisiera invertir el resultado, es decir pasar las filas como columnas y columas a filas utilizando pivot - unpivot.

Esta es mi resultado que deseo invertir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi consulta SQL para invertir el resultado (con error).

```
Select TI_MOVI_CAJA, SUM_TOTA from
(
Select TI_MOVI_CAJA, SUM_TOTA from #IMPORTES
) p
UNPIVOT (
SUM_TOTA FOR TI_MOVI_CAJA IN (I, E)
) AS UNPVT;
```

Comment: Para pasar de filas a columnas se usa `PIVOT`. Para pasar de columnas a filas se usa `UNPIVOT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta agregando **I,E** en tu subconsulata P, ya que falta conocer el campo **I,E** en el caso se resolver el unpivot

Ejemplo  :

```
Select TI_MOVI_CAJA, SUM_TOTA from
(
Select I, E from #IMPORTES
) p
UNPIVOT (
SUM_TOTA FOR TI_MOVI_CAJA IN (I, E)
) AS UNPVT;
```

otra opción según lo que se comprendió en tu requerimiento

```
Select 
case when TI_MOVI_CAJA='E' then SUM_TOTA else 0 end as E,
case when TI_MOVI_CAJA='I' then SUM_TOTA else 0 end as I,    
from #IMPORTES
```

Comment: Me devuelve el siguiente error: El nombre de columna "TI_MOVI_CAJA" especificado en el operador UNPIVOT está en conflicto con el nombre de columna existente en el argumento UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolverlo con la siguiente consulta, Gracias.

```
Select 
I AS INGRESOS,
E AS EGRESOS, 
(I - E) AS TOTAL from
(
Select TI_MOVI_CAJA, SUM_TOTA from #IMPORTES
) p
PIVOT 
(
MAX(SUM_TOTA)
FOR TI_MOVI_CAJA IN (I, E)
) AS UNPVT;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor considera explicar tu aporte para saber cómo esto soluciona tu problema

Comment: Por favor considera explicar tu aporte para saber cómo esto soluciona tu problema